# Wrong general total in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-custom-visuals

I want to calculate the Herfindalh-Hirschmann Index (sum of market shares at square) by videogame publisher. In Power BI, i have 2 measures, the market share and the square of market share for each publisher. My calculations are good but the general total is false for the square of market share.

[image: Issue with total]

My DAX code is this for the Market Share (correct calculation & total) :

```
Market Share = VAR Volume = SUM('Sales - Global'[Sales])
VAR AllVolume = CALCULATE(SUM('Sales - Global'[Sales]), ALL('Publisher'))
RETURN DIVIDE(Volume, AllVolume)
```

My DAX code is this for the Squared Market Share. I ant to conserve the (*100) to better interprete the result. Calculations are good but the general total is incorrect. :

```
Market Share Square = 
VAR Volume = SUM('Sales - Global'[Sales])
VAR AllVolume = CALCULATE(SUM('Sales - Global'[Sales]), ALL('Publisher'[Publisher]))
VAR MarketShare = DIVIDE(Volume, AllVolume)*100
RETURN
    MarketShare * MarketShare
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use [`SUMX`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/sumx-function-dax) to calculate the value for each row and then sum.

```
Market Share Square v2 = 
  var allVol = CALCULATE(SUM('Sales - Global'[Sales]), ALL('Publisher'[Publisher]))
  return SUMX(
    'Publisher',
    (
      var vol = CALCULATE(SUM('Sales - Global'[Sales]))
      var mktShare = DIVIDE(vol, allVol) * 100
      return mktShare * mktShare
    )
  )
```